# Swiper Element (WebComponent) not working on vue3

Tags: vuejs3, swiper.js

Im trying to use the swiper element on vue3, following the doc's instructions, but it's not working. I did the 'npm install swiper' first and now my package.json has this info:

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "swiper": "^11.0.7",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
```

But when I add the code below:

```js
// import function to register Swiper custom elements
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
// register Swiper custom elements
register();
```

I got the following error:

This dependency was not found:

```
* swiper/element/bundle in ./src/main.js
```

Im trying this code inside my main.js file.

Something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Im just following the docs instructions.

Comment: did you do step 1, `npm install swiper`?  what does your package.json file look like?  [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78177503/edit) your question with the information.

Comment: why are you using it you should use `swiper/vue` i remember before the doc said we should use `webcomponent` but i don't care `swiper/vue` is still available on latest version

Comment: Thanks @yoduh, I edited my question as you suggested.

Comment: @TachibanaShin, I'm trying to use that because of the message on the top of the swiper/vue documentation: "Swiper Vue components will likely to be removed in future versions. It is recommended to migrate to Swiper Element instead.", just because of that, once is a new project, Im trying to start it using the newest swiper approach.

Comment: Please keep using `swiper/vue`. If it is discontinued I will maintain it

Comment: I say this is for your benefit. even if you register successfully it has annoying errors. the error being encountered is due to the import handler you can specify `swiper/element-bundle.js` file directly instead of using the specified alias

Comment: Ok @TachibanaShin, I can do that, (keep using swiper/vue), but could you explain me how it works? For example, I supose that if in 6 monts it´s discontinued, it´ll stop working on my project 'cause it depends on something on the swiper repository, or am I wrong? Sorry but Im new to this wolrd :/.

Comment: If `swiper/vue` is discontinued in the next 6 months, your project will continue to operate without any problems